# Text orientation in 3D

Tags: plotting

Text orientation works fine in 2D:

```
Graphics[{Text["ABCDEF", {0, 0}, Automatic, {1, 1}]}]
```

But it doesn't work in 3D:

```
Graphics3D[{Text["ABCDEF", {0, 0, 0}, Automatic, {0, 1, 0}]}]
```

If I use a 2D direction in Graphics3D:

```
Graphics3D[{Text["ABCDEF", {0, 0, 0}, Automatic, {0, 1}]}]
```

it seems that orientation is correct, but Mathematica prints an error message:

> Text offset Automatic should be a pair of numbers.

Actually I don't understand the meaning of keyword `Automatic` here.

Comment: Looks like `Automatic` can be used as offset specification in 3D for some reason. You can use the explicit setting `{0,0}` instead, which is equivalent to `Center` and `Automatic` (at least in 2D where they work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that for 3D the offset inputs are still 2D. It doesn't look like it can translate or rotate the text in or out of the screen.

To make your example work you can do

```
Graphics3D[{Text["ABCDEF", {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}]}]
```

The amount to translate `{0, 0}` part can be whatever you want and shifts the initial plotting point. Try

```
Manipulate[{Graphics3D[{Text[
     "ABCDEF", {0, 0, 0}, {a, b}, {1, 1}]}]}, {{a, 0}, -4, 
  4}, {{b, 0}, -4, 4}]
```

The error says it expects a pair of numbers. `Automatic` is equivalent to `Center` which I'm guessing is a triple for `Graphics3D`.

Modifying this 2D example from [`Text`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html)

```
Graphics[Table[
  Text[Style["Mathematica", Hue[RandomReal[]], Italic, 
    RandomInteger[{10, 30}]], RandomReal[1, {2}], Automatic, 
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}]], {20}], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

to work in 3D is

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[Text[
   Style["Mathematica", Hue[RandomReal[]], Italic, 
    RandomInteger[{10, 30}]], RandomReal[1, {3}], {0, 0}, 
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}]], {20}], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why the text looks a little bit blurry when rotated:
`Graphics3D[{
  Text[Style["ABCDEF", Large], {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}],
  Text[Style["ABCDEF", Large], {0, 0, 0}]
  }]`

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it gets blurry when rotated in 3D. It seems fine in 2D. But, the `Antialiasing` documentation says "`Antialiasing` does not alter the appearance of fonts. Font antialiasing is typically controlled by a global operating system setting." and that "`Antialiasing` does not alter the appearance of `Graphics3D` objects. 3D graphical antialiasing is a global property of the renderer controlled by the "HardwareAntialiasingQuality" suboption of `RenderingOptions`."